# json_normalize None handling change (pandas .23)

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have jsons containing nested values that are sometimes `None` and the behavior has changed between pandas 0.22.0 and pandas 0.23.0.

In 0.22.0:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
my_json = {'event': {'name': 'Bob', 'id': '12345','id2': None},
           'id': '12345', 'labels': []}
json_normalize(my_json)
```

gives:

```
event.id    event.id2   event.name  id      labels
12345       None        Bob         12345   []
```

which I want.

In 0.23.0:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
my_json = {'event': {'name': 'Bob', 'id': '12345','id2': None},
           'id': '12345', 'labels': []}
json_normalize(my_json)
```

returns `KeyError: 'id2'`

Toggling ignore errors does nothing, and it's not really feasible to change the nested `None`s to placeholder values. Anyone know how to achieve the prior behavior with the update?

Comment: This may be a result of a different [bugfix](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19417). I don't use this enough to know whether the two are related, but it is documented that they changed this module in 0.23.

Comment: Scratch that, [quite a lot changed](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html) if you search for `json_`

Comment: There is an issue open for my [problem](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21158) . Apparently handling of nested None changed.

Comment: looks like this has been fixed, had to get latest pandas 0.23.3